# How do I find current users mailbox through shell (command line)

Tags: linux, terminal, mail-command

I am using ssh to login to a remote linux box on a capture the flag site, to trying to learn linux fundamentals, and one of the questions asks "What is the path to the htb-student's mail?". I am not sure how to achieve this through the terminal. Can I get some advice?

Things I have tried:

```
locate htb-student 
locate mail | grep student
find mail
find mailx
ls ~
locate ****/**** | grep mail | grep htb-student
```

most of these return nothing. The `locate *` and everything grep filter was out of desperation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the environment variable `MAIL`

```
$ env | grep MAIL
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/thanasis
```

If you want to find this variable for a different user, you should have access to run it with `su` command, e.g. if you are the root user and need to find it for any other user.

Usually this path for all users is under `/var/spool/mail` and some links also exist (like `/var/mail`).

Comment: Thank you so much <3

Answer (score 1):

the usage of `find` command is:

`find / -name 'mail' 2> /dev/null`

1. / - is the location where it searches
2. -name 'mail' - is the query to search
3. 2> - error messages will be redirected to nowhere (to avoid error messages to be displayed on terminal)

Comment: This will be really useful building a keyword search in my .bash_profile thank you

Comment: The spool file _may_ be called `mail`, but more commonly has the same name as the user.

Comment: @Patrick-not-spongebob, if it's useful, you can give them an up arrow vote.